# vim split when filename is a script output

Tags: vim, vi

I have a script `fn <regex>` that gives me the full path to a file whose name meets the regex string that I supply (or more than one, if there is more than one match).

The question is, how do I split in vim and open the "output" file in the split window.

I tried `:sp !fn my_file.name` and got

> E172: Only one file name allowed

Note, that I also tried `:sp !fn my_file.name | xargs echo -n` which removes the trailing new-line, but got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but I came up with this code:

```
com! -nargs=+ Sp call s:open_multiple_splits(<q-args>)

fu! s:open_multiple_splits(script) abort
    let files = systemlist(a:script)
    for file in files
        if !empty(glob(file, 0, 1))
            exe 'split '.file
        endif
    endfor
endfu
```

It assumes that your script is a shell script and not a Vim script.

I tested it by creating the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo /tmp/foo
echo /tmp/bar
```

Which I wrote inside `/tmp/sh.sh`, and made executable (`chmod +x /tmp/sh.sh`).
I also created 2 files `/tmp/foo` and `/tmp/bar`:

```
echo 'hello' >/tmp/foo
echo 'world' >/tmp/bar
```

Then, in Vim, I typed `:Sp /tmp/sh.sh`, and it opened 2 horizontal viewports, displaying `/tmp/foo` and `/tmp/bar`.

Note that if your script only outputs one filepath, you don't need all this code, you could simply use backtick-expansion (see `:h backtick-expansion`):

```
:sp `your_script`
```